# logical bug in my code in java... in switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int operator;
        double number1, number2, result;
        boolean ask = true;
        while (ask) {

        System.out.println("please select your operator:\n"
                + "1 for +\n" +
                "2 for -\n" +
                "3 for *\n" +
                "4 for %\n" +
                "");
        operator = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("you chose " + operator + " operator babe");


            System.out.println("please enter your first number");
            Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            number1 = numberScanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("please enter your second number");
            Scanner numberScanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            number2 = numberScanner2.nextDouble();


            switch (operator) {
                case 1:
                    result = number1 + number2;
                    System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = number1 - number2;
                    System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = number1 * number2;
                    System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = number1 / number2;
                    System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("you chosen the wrong operator babe :)");
                    break;
            }


            System.out.println("do yo want to continue?\n" +
                    "y for yes\n" +
                    "n for no\n");
            char askInput = myScanner.next().charAt(0);
            if (askInput=='n') ask=false;
        }
    }
}
```

i got trouble in my switch case
if i press any number or letter somthing like 5 or 6 or... it should print `you chose wrong operator`.

i think problem is in my default but i don't know where is it?

Comment: well than you should actually put the `switch` statement at a position BEFORE you want to input numbers for a valid option and after the FIRST user input and not in the end. How should it tell you that it´s the wrong input when, after the first input, you instantly start reading two numbers, and check the option the user did chose AFTERWARDS. Try inputting `5`, afterwards 2 numbers and you´ll then recieve the message you want.

Comment: after i chose for example 5 it continue and accept 5 but logicaly it must not accept 5 and default should run

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as for my comment, if you want to validate the input the user does (for the option) before having the user input another 2 numbers, than, yeah you should actually programm it that way that the validation goes RIGHT AFTER the first userinput. Here´s a slightly corrected version of your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int operator;
    double result;
    boolean ask = true;
    Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (ask) {

        System.out.println(
                "please select your operator:\n" + "1 for +\n" + "2 for -\n" + "3 for *\n" + "4 for %\n" + "");
        operator = numberScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("you chose " + operator + " operator babe");

        // Here was your "Mistake". You instantly started asking the user for another input,
        // but actually wanted to ahve the switch statment here

        switch (operator) {
        case 1:
            result = get_num1(numberScanner) + get_num2(numberScanner);
            System.out.println("result is:" + result);
            break;
        case 2:
            result = get_num1(numberScanner) - get_num2(numberScanner);
            System.out.println("result is:" + result);
            break;
        case 3:
            result = get_num1(numberScanner) * get_num2(numberScanner);
            System.out.println("result is:" + result);
            break;
        case 4:
            result = get_num1(numberScanner) % get_num2(numberScanner);
            System.out.println("result is:" + result);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("you chosen the wrong operator babe :)");
            break;

        }

        System.out.println("do yo want to continue?\n" + "y for yes\n" + "n for no\n");
        char askInput = numberScanner.next().charAt(0);
        if (askInput == 'n')
            ask = false;
    }
}

public static double get_num1(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("please enter your first number");
    return scanner.nextDouble();
}

public static double get_num2(Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.println("please enter your second number");
    return scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: tnx to you dear

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder your code like this

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int operator;
    double number1, number2, result;
    boolean ask = true;
    while (ask) {
        System.out.println("please enter your first number");
        Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        number1 = numberScanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("please enter your second number");
        Scanner numberScanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        number2 = numberScanner2.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("please select your operator:\n"
                + "1 for +\n"
                + "2 for -\n"
                + "3 for *\n"
                + "4 for %\n"
                + "");
        operator = myScanner.nextInt();

        switch (operator) {
            case 1:
                result = number1 + number2;
                System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                break;
            case 2:
                result = number1 - number2;
                System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                break;
            case 3:
                result = number1 * number2;
                System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                break;
            case 4:
                result = number1 / number2;
                System.out.println("result is:" + result);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("you chosen the wrong operator babe :)");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("you chose " + operator + " operator babe");

        System.out.println("do yo want to continue?\n"
                + "y for yes\n"
                + "n for no\n");
        char askInput = myScanner.next().charAt(0);
        if (askInput == 'n') {
            ask = false;
        }
    }
}`
```

and you'll be fine

Answer (score -1):

simply you could validate the operator while you assign it with the input.

for example use if condition and check whether its between 1 and 5 and if not print whatever you want

Answer (score -1):

2 things:

you dont need 2 scanners using only one will be enough

the code is behaving so because you go into the switch case AFTER asking the numbers you want to operate...

some condition like:

```
operator = myScanner.nextInt();
if (operator < 1 || operator > 4) {

 }
```

may help....